# Gmail view Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to know what kind of view does Google uses in Gmail, I know that the inbox is created using a `RecyclerView`, but what about when the email is expanded?
At first, I thought Gmail starts a new intent, but it doesn't seem so, I tried to look if it was a `CardView`, but I cannot find any result neither on Google.
I'm interested because I would like to make an app that uses a similar view, but I don't know what kind of view Google uses.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, they are using Fragments. because the app bar is not being reloaded and the whole behaviour of the content.

**Anyway**, there are a lot of ways to implement this kind of behaviour. one of them is using Fragments (as I mentioned before), another one is just a new intent.